# Is there a better way to join sub lists with a remainder unchanged?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Suppose I have:

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j'], ['k']]
```

And from that, I want to join pairs but leave a remainder element unchanged like so:

```
[["a_b", "c_d", "e"], ["f_g", "h"], ["i_j"], ["k"]]
```

Closest I have (that produces the result) is:

```
r = a.map { |sl| 
  tmp = []
  sl.each_slice(2) { |a, b| tmp << (b.nil? ? a : "#{a}_#{b}") }
  tmp
}
```

Alternatively:

```
r = a.map { |sl| 
  tmp = []
  sl.each_slice(2) { |a, b| tmp << (b.nil? ? a : [a,b].join("_")) }
  tmp
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a cleaner way to do this?

- `each_slice` returns an `Enumerator` if no block is given.
- `Enumerator` responds to `map`
- `map` will yield the full "sliced" sub array to the block
- `each_slice` does not guarantee an `n` element array. If the slice is uneven then it will just yield what is left.

Knowing all of this your implementation can be simplified to:

```
a.map { |s1| s1.each_slice(2).map { |e| e.join("_") } }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks!!! Suggestion: Add a bullet `join` returns the single elements unchanged (except if there is a `nil` in the second element as you were filtering...)

Comment: @dawg if there is  `nil` and you don't want to represent this as an element then I would use `e.compact.join('_')` instead. It does not technically "return the single elements unchanged" as the resulting string will be a different object from the original.

Comment: I was referring to `['f', 'g', 'h']` being sliced to `.each_slice(2) { |a, b|` where the second time through you get `a='h'` and `b=nil`.

Comment: @dawg only because you are decomposing the Array. If we change your example to `.each_slice(2) { |a|` then first iteration `a == ['f', 'g']` and second iteration `a == ['h']` not `['h', nil]`